# Nestjs TypeOrm postgresql using custom schema

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

In my Nestjs TypeOrm app, I'd like tu encapsulate all my db artifacts in a schema named `globe`. So, I indicate the schema in my `ormconfig.ts`

```
const DatabaseConfigForMigrations = {
  name: 'countrydb',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  schema: 'globe',
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['dist/src/**/*entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/src/migrations/**/*.js'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
  options: { trustServerCertificate: true },
};
```

also in my models. Such as;

```
@Entity({ schema: 'globe' })
@ObjectType()
export class City {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field(() => Int)
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  touristic: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  population: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Country, (country) => country.cities)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'country_id' })
  country: Country;

  @Column({ type: 'int', name: 'country_id' })
  countryId: number;
}
```

However, when I run `yarn migration:run` unfortunately, `error: error: schema "globe" does not exist` happens.

How can I have TypeOrm create my tables in my `globe` schema?

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit tricky and strange having to use explicitly the typeorm's url connection option and then specify the schema inside its search_path option to get it to work for me.

e.g. ormconfig.js

```
    module.exports = {
      type: 'postgres',
      url: `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}?options=-c%20search_path=globe`,
      ...
```

Comment: Couldn't do it. Should I also set schema for each model explicitly?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could give a sample github repo :-)

Comment: I have almost exactly what you had above except in ormconfig.js + url parameter.

One more point, I am using:
    "typeorm": "^0.2.31",

Comment: can you please just take a look;

https://github.com/killjoy2013/graphql-nestjs 

you can try it out by docker-compose up   &   yarn migration:run

Comment: I reckon you should insert the following line into, says, line no. 10 of  https://github.com/killjoy2013/graphql-nestjs/blob/06-auth/ormconfig.ts  



`url: \`postgresql://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}?options=-c%20search_path=globe\`,
`